# Providing iOS app first as WebApp, then same app as Native App

Tags: ios, web-applications, app-store

I have a WebApp built with jQuery Mobile which I plan to wrap up with PhoneGap and then release it in the Apple App-Store.
Afterwards, I want to copy exactly the same functionality and build the same App again, this time natively with Xcode. This version, I would like to release in the AppStore for a higher price.

Which is the best strategy here? Will Apple allow me to release two versions of the same App? The two versions will have exactly the same functionality, the native one just runs a little smoother and looks a little better, because it's native.
Or do I have to provide the native version as an update to the WebApp? In that case, would I be able to increase the price of the App?